# Absolutely position div sits behind textbox in IE7

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer-7

I'm having issues with an absolutely positioned custom drop down, in IE7 the div is sitting behind a normal textbox which is not position in any special way.
I've already read this topic: [IE7 puts absolutely positioned div underneath, ignores z-index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385513/ie7-puts-absolutely-positioned-div-underneath-ignores-z-index) but the solutions didn't help me.

The difference between my code and the person who asked the above question is that my div is being created through javascript using document.write and adding it through appendChild

```
addEvent(document.getElementById("storeDown"), "click", showRegions);
var showRegions = function(e) {
        var dd = getTarget(e);
        if(document.getElementById("regionOptions")) {
            dd.parentNode.removeChild(document.getElementById("regionOptions"));
            regionsShowing = false;
        } else {
            var ddNode = document.createElement("div");
            ddNode.id = "regionOptions";
            ddNode.style.backgroundColor = offColor;
            var optNode;
            for(var region in storeList) {
                optNode = document.createElement("div");
                optNode.innerHTML = region;
                ddNode.appendChild(optNode);
            }
            dd.parentNode.appendChild(ddNode);
            regionsShowing = true;
        }
        cancelEvent(e);
    }
```

My parent div has a z-index of 500 and is positioned relative and regionOptions is positioned absolute and I tried to also add a z-index to it but it didn't make a difference.

Comment: You say it is different, it is still the same as the one you linked too. Give the parent node a z-index and set it to relative.

Comment: Apparently it does make a difference that I'm appending it after the page has been loaded already and the indexes have been assigned to elements, check out my answer below, thanks!

Comment: I run into the problem all the time with dynamic content. Your solution just changed where the content is loaded so you avoided the issue. Not knowing your HTML structure makes your solution not helpful for others.

Comment: I would love to show you the HTML but this is for a site that hasn't gone live yet and there's nothing really special about it, it's just a form contained in a wrapper div and about 10 textboxes for things like name, address, age etc.. and 3 buttons at the bottom (submit, home, reset), I attached my child node to the buttons div after all the textboxes so it's right at the bottom in the code, then absolutely positioned it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay finally figured it out, I changed where it appends so it's appended in a div at the bottom of the page after all the textboxes (in my case, a buttons div), so instead of `dd.parentNode.appendChild(ddNode)`, it's now `document.getElementbyId("buttons").appendChild(ddNode)`, but also had to change the CSS so it's absolute positioned in relative to the page wrapper rather than the specific div, and it seems to have fixed it.